# Gitlab-CI Laravel unit testing fails online but works locally

Tags: php, laravel, testing, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a similar issue as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695165/test-fails-only-in-gitlab-ci-locally-successful): My unit/feature test work locally, but fail online. I have already figured out that the test which fail are probably related to the *Laravel Storage API* which is used with the local driver.

This is the code is suspect is causing issues.

```php
            // DELETE IF EXISTS
            if (Storage::exists($path))
                Storage::delete($path);

            // COPY BOILERPLATE
            Storage::copy('bp-template.py', $path);

            // APPEND
            Storage::append($path, $validator['complexFormula']);
```

In my `.env.testing` file, I have set

```sh
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
```

I created the docker image for testing by following [these](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/#create-a-container-image) instructions.

Comment: You should mock the `Storage` facade in testing. [`Storage::fake()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#storage-fake).

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks for your comment - if you had written an answer, I could have marked this as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BrianThompson suggested, I implemented a [mock storage disk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#storage-fake) which solved my problem.